Is the arc length of curve parameterisations which belong to different equivalence classes different?
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a curve.
Two parameterisations $\gamma_1: I_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma_2: I_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of $\mathcal{C}$ are equivalent iff there exists a differentiable bijection $\varphi: I_1 \to I_2$ with the following properties for all $t \in I_1$:

$\varphi'(t) \ne 0$
$\gamma_2(\varphi(t)) = \gamma_1(t)$

It has been proven that if two parameterisations $\gamma_1: [a;b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma_2: [c;d] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, then
$$\int_a^b ||\gamma_1'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_c^d ||\gamma_2'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$$
This allows us to uniquely define the arc length of $\mathcal{C}$, or at least it seems so at first. However, are we sure that parameterisations from different equivalence classes yield the same value for the integral? For example, there could be two other parameterisations $\gamma_3: [\alpha; \beta] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma_4: [\delta; \epsilon] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_4$ are equivalent to each other but they are equivalent to neither $\gamma_1$ nor $\gamma_2$. Are we certain that
$$\int_a^b ||\gamma_1'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_c^d ||\gamma_2'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_\alpha^\beta ||\gamma_3'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_\delta^\epsilon ||\gamma_4'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$$
If not, then there are different possible "arc lengths", so how do we know which one to choose? If yes, then how do we prove this?

@YvesDaoust the chain rule is used in the proof that
$\int_a^b ||\gamma_1'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_c^d ||\gamma_2'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\int_\alpha^\beta ||\gamma_3'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_\delta^\epsilon ||\gamma_4'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$, but you cannot use it to prove the stronger statement
$\int_a^b ||\gamma_1'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_c^d ||\gamma_2'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_\alpha^\beta ||\gamma_3'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_\delta^\epsilon ||\gamma_4'(t)|| \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$.

What is your definition of a parametrization?

@Lorago a continuous function $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined on an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Then how can you consider $\gamma'$ at all?

Okay, yeah, I should have mentioned that I am talking about differentiable parameterisations of a differentiable curve.

Are you even talking about continuously differentiable parametrizations? We need the derivatives to be integrable too somehow

Being so pedantic is not helpful. Obviously, if my question contains derivatives and integrals, then I expect the functions to be differentiable and integrable...

@mdkovachev What's your definition of curve? It should be the class of all equivalent parametrisations

@Dog_69 the definition I use for a curve is a subset $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ for which there exists a continuous function $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ on an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma(I) = \mathcal{C}$.

@Dr.TonyTonyChopper I do not want anything to be true, I am asking whether something is. I assume that you talk about two line segments in your example - in this case, they are made up of different points and so they are different curves and thus my question can no longer asked. My question is about four parameterizations $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,\gamma_4$ of the same curve (i.e. same image) such that $\gamma_1$ is equivalent to $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ is equivalent to $\gamma_4$ but it is not necessarily true that $\gamma_1$ is equivalent to $\gamma_3$.

@mdkovachev Yes, that could happen. That's exactly why curves are defined as equivalence classes of parametrisations. Being a bit pedantic, a ($C^k$-) curve is a $C^k$ manifold of dimension one. If you look up the definition of smooth manifold on Wiki you'll see that it involves either a maximal atlas or an equivalence class of atlases.

In practise, the above means that there may exist parametrisations $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ with the same image and the same arc-length but belonging to different equivalent classes (i.e. that are not equivalent), and so the curves they defined, thought of as equivalence classes of equivalent parametrisations, are different.

Do you require that parameterizations are injective?

We should be accurate with the notions of a curve and its length.
I am weak in differential geometry and I used a small book [GZ] to study it when I was a student.
It is good, but introductive and very brief.
According to it, a parametrically defined curve in $\mathbb R^n$ is a continuous map $r:(a,b)\to\mathbb R^n$, where $a<b$ are real numbers. The image $r((a,b))$ is called the supporter of the parametrically defined curve. But, as far as I know (see, for instance Problem 6.3.14 from [Eng]), the supporters can be specific. Namely, continuous images in $\mathbb R^n$ of a closed segment are exactly nonempty compact connected locally connected subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. For instance, a square is such a set.
So later they considers curves which are sufficiently smooth, that is when the function $f$ has continuous derivatives up to the $r$th order, where the number $r$ as big as is needed that all the considerations have a sense.
Later they additionally assume that $r'(\tau)\ne 0$ for each $\tau\in (a,b)$. And if $t_0,t\in (a,b)$  then the value $\int_{t_0}^t \|r'(\tau)\|d\tau$ is called the (oriented) length of the curve $r$ between $t_0$ and $t_1$ (I guess, here is a misprint are there should be $t$ instead of $t_1$).
A thorough, but different approach is developed in $\S$4 of Chapter 7 in the good old (and so less rigorous) book [Fich]. It takes about ten pages long and is based on the plane case. As I understood, here a curve is an image by a continuous map (which I rename to $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$) from a segment (which I rename to $[a,b]$) to the plane $\mathbb R^2$. The map $r$ is required to be injective, but the case of the closed curve, when the images of the segment endpoints coincide. The order on the segment $[a,b]$ induces the direction (circular for the case of the closed curve) on the curve. It is shown that the direction (up to reverse) does not depend on a parametrization of the curve.
Let $a\le t_0<t_1\dots<t_n \le b$. A broken line with the consecutive vertices $r(t_0),r(t_1),\dots, r(t_n)$ is called inscribed in the curve. The length of the curve is defined as the supremum of the lengths of the broken lines inscribed in it. Since the direction (up to reverse) does not depend on a parametrization of the curve, so does its length. If the length is finite then the curve is called rectifiable. It [248, Fich] it is shown that the curve is rectifiable provided there exist continuous derivatives $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ and that the derivative $s'(t)$ of the oriented length of the curve equals $\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}$. This justifies the integral expressions for the curve lengths like in your question.
Moreover, Jordan introduced a notion of a function with bounded variation to study curve rectifiability. According to Jordan theorem, the curve is rectifiable iff both functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ have the bounded variation at the segment $[a,b]$, see [572, Fich3].
References
[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, General Topology, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.
[Fich] Grigorii Fichtenholz, Differential and Integral Calculus, v. I, 5-th edition, Moscow: Fizmatgiz, 1962, in Russian.
[Fich3] Grigorii Fichtenholz, Differential and Integral Calculus, v. III, 4-th edition, Moscow: Nauka, 1966, in Russian.
[GZ] I.Y.Guran, M.M. Zarichnyi, Differential geometry and topology, Kyiv, 1991, in Ukrainian.

In a comment you write

The definition I use for a curve is a subset $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ for which there exists a continuous function $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^n$  on an interval $I \subset \mathbb R$ such that $\gamma(I)=C$.

I discussed the concept of a curve in my answer to How can there be two congruent curves (eg, $y=x^3$ and $y=x^{1/3}$), one smooth and the other not?
Actually there are two related concepts: A curve can be understood as a parameterized curve which is a continuous map $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^n$ or as a subset $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ which is the image of a parameterized curve $\gamma$. In the second case let us call $\gamma$ a parameterization of $C$.
If $\gamma$ is differentiable with continuous derivative, we say that $\gamma$ is a smoothly parameterized curve (it seems that you only consider such parameterizations). Then you define the arclength of $\gamma$ as
$$L(\gamma) = \int_a^b \lVert \gamma'(t) \rVert dt .$$
This can be interpreted as the distance travelled along the path given by $\gamma$. In order that $L(\gamma)$ can be understood as the arclength of the image $C = \gamma(I)$ we need to make additional assumptions; the requirement $\gamma(I) = C$ is too broad. For example, let $C$ be  the unit circle in  $\mathbb R^2$. In the sense of your definition it has the parameterizations
$$\gamma_n : [0,n] \to \mathbb R^2, \gamma_n(t) = (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$$
which give
$$L(\gamma_n) =\int_0^n \lVert \gamma_n'(t) \rVert dt = 2\pi n .$$
The problem is that a parameterization of a curve $C$ (which is just a subset of $\mathbb R^n$) can run several times through parts of $C$ which can increase the arclength arbitrarily.
There are two approaches to solve this problem:

Do not consider the arclength of curves $C$, but only the arclength of parameterized curves $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^n$.

Do not allow that parameterizations of $C$ run several times through parts of $C$.


In the first approach no problem arises. We have an equivalence relation for smoothly parameterized curves, and equivalent smoothly parameterized curves have the same length.
The second case essentially boils down to consider only curves which have injective smooth parameterizations (call them elementary curves). We can generalize this a bit by considering curves which can be split into pieces with this property, but for the sake of simplicity we shall not do this here.
For an elementary curve $C$ with injective smooth parameterization $\gamma$ we define
$$L(C) = L(\gamma) \tag{1}.$$
But now your question is justified: Is this well-defined if we work with non-equivalent injective smooth parameterizations?  Note that such do exist (see again How can there be two congruent curves (eg, $y=x^3$ and $y=x^{1/3}$), one smooth and the other not?).
Nevertheless $(1)$ is well-defined. To see this, one has to consider so-called rectifiable parameterized curves. See Alex Ravsky's answer or here. It may also be useful to consult a textbook covering this topic. The following facts are well-known:

Rectifiable parameterized curves $\gamma$ have a well-defined arclength.
Smoothly parameterized curves $\gamma$ are rectifiable with arclength $L(\gamma)$.
Call rectifiable parameterized curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ equivalent if there exists a homeomorphism $\phi : I_1 \to I_2$ such that $\gamma_2 \circ \phi = \gamma_1$. Then equivalent rectifiable parameterized curves have the same arclength.

Now consider any two smoothly parameterized injective curves with the same image. Then they are equivelent in the sense of $(3)$ and have the same arclength.
